# Android Studio Unable install updates/New packages in Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio in my Mac. It is installed with basic packages. Now I am trying into install other Updates/New packages. But, it is failed with timeout error. 
[image]

Please suggest that what is configuration seems to be missing...?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a network issue: you have multiple timeout relative to local address 192.168.12.10. Check your network settings and wifi and ethernet wires.